# Unpivot columns using CROSS APPLY where values include int and varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I am attempting to unpivot a table column but am encountering a conversion error from varchar to int. All of the columns in my table are ints except one, which is varchar. The error is detailed below.

I don't want to use any type of conversion.

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'View Test' to data type int.

```
DECLARE @tableData AS TABLE 
(
    TD_ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    View0 INT, 
    View1 INT,
    View2 INT,
    Remarks Varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO @tableData (View0, View1, View2, Remarks)
VALUES(1, 0, 1, 'View Test')

SELECT column_Name, column_value
FROM @tableData
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES
    ('View0',View0)
    , ('View1',View1)
    , ('View2',View2)
    , ('Remarks',Remarks)
) Q (column_Name, column_value)
```

Comment: All values in a `VALUES` constructor must have the same type... and if they don't, SQL Server uses its type precedence to determine which to try and convert them to. Therefore while any of `View0`, `View1` or `View2` is an int, it will try and convert all values in that column, including `Remarks` into an int. If you are happy with a string output, then convert them all to varchar first.

Comment: Dear @DaleK, I already know how to solve this problem, but I do not want to cast anything.

Comment: You don't have any choice about the casting as per my first comment. There is no other way. A column in SQL server can only be a single data type.

Comment: If you don't want to cast then what is the expected behavior? You can't have a column that has three int values and one varchar.

Comment: Anything else we can help you with? Else you may as well delete this question.

Answer (score 2):

Like @Dale K said, you can convert to varchar first. Here is the sample code:

```
DECLARE @tableData AS TABLE (
    TD_ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    View0 INT,
    View1 INT,
    View2 INT,
    Remarks Varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO @tableData (View0, View1, View2, Remarks)
VALUES (1, 0, 1, 'View Test')

SELECT column_Name, column_value
FROM (
    SELECT
        CAST(View0 AS VARCHAR(20)) AS View0,
        CAST(View1 AS VARCHAR(20)) AS View1,
        CAST(View2 AS VARCHAR(20)) AS View2,
        Remarks
    FROM @tableData
) src
UNPIVOT (
    column_value FOR column_Name IN (View0, View1, View2, Remarks)
) unpvt;
```

Here is the [fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/-bc0_rPD)

Or you can use like this too:

```
SELECT column_Name, column_value
FROM @tableData
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES
    ('View0', CAST(View0 AS VARCHAR(20))),
    ('View1', CAST(View1 AS VARCHAR(20))),
    ('View2', CAST(View2 AS VARCHAR(20))),
    ('Remarks', Remarks)
) Q (column_Name, column_value)
```

Here is the [fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/tmcm4QH6)

Comment: A good answers contains an explanation in addition to a solution. Also, why change to using a PIVOT when OP is already using CROSS APPLY which is perfectly OK?

Comment: Because the tags is unpivot, so I use syntax `unpivot`.But, yes, I will add the cross apply things too

Comment: You should also add an explanation as to what you fixed

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scrimp on conversion but waste some typing you can use OPENJSON as a middle-man to do it for you:

```sql
DECLARE @tableData AS TABLE 
(
    TD_ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    View0 INT, 
    View1 INT,
    View2 INT,
    Remarks Varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO @tableData (View0, View1, View2, Remarks)
VALUES(1, 0, 1, 'View Test')

SELECT oj.[key], oj.value, o.[key]
FROM OPENJSON((SELECT *
FROM @tableData
FOR JSON PATH)) o
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(o.value) oj
WHERE oj.[key] <> 'TD_ID'
```

Openjson can return values in form of "key" / "value", which we do here, by:

1. Converting your table data into json.
2. Re-opening it by OPENJSON, which returns an list of rows of json objects (the `o` alias part)
3. Opening each json object to return values in key/value form (the `oj` alias part)

You could skip the 3rd part in your example and do `OPENJSON(..., '$[0]') o` to directly get the values, but this will only work for single row tables.

I would say that while this is a possible approach, the best way is still to do your casting properly